# UIAlertController Xcode 9.1 automatic Alert truncating

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uialertcontroller, xcode9.1

In my app I am presenting with UIAlertController, with title and message. Where the message getting truncated with single line. Not only for one project it's repeating in every project. What may be the cause & solution ? thanks in advance.

tested in Device : `iPhone 7` , Tool : `Xcode 9.1`

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you share your current UIAlertController code?

Comment: @muazhud I have updated with sample code

Comment: I had run the code and everything is ok. The message doesn't get truncated. How do you set the title & message for the UIAlertController?

Comment: How did you solve it?